# Recreate Wavestation Mini Lead

Tags: music

The Korg Wavestation synthesizer had a popular patch called Mini Lead, most notably used in the Genesis track *Fading Lights* by keyboardist Tony Banks.

Here is an audio demo of the patch in itself: http://www.synthmania.com/Korg%20Wavestation%20A-D/Audio/ROM/04%20Mini%20Lead.mp3

Here is an extended improvisation using it:

And here is the original synth solo (at 4:13):

Now everywhere I look people say

> Buy the Wavestation, that's the only way to have this sound.

I don't believe them :) How to recreate this?

Comment: To clarify, this is a "sound programming for fun" type of question. I could always buy the Korg Legacy Wavestation VST if I needed the sound pronto.

Comment: It uses the wave sequence feature, so it's like wavetable synthesis. Not sure how the tables were made though.

Comment: @absence I know that, and what I hear is the same sample being morphed into 1 or 2 octaves higher version of itself. But the interesting part really is how that sample was originally created. I can get somewhat close on my synth but I still get a very robotic sounding lead, not an organic one.

Comment: It's morphed into different waveforms, not into different octaves of the same waveform. But I agree, the interesting part is how those waveforms were made. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different waveforms that are sequenced with crossfading (without power law, so there's a slight tremolo effect) seem to be made with hard synced pulse wave, and some of them are an octave above the others.

Comment: I've now found that the octave shift happens by itself at a certain sync setting.

Comment: An upwards octave shift happens when the slave osc frequency is an integer multiple of the master osc frequency, but then you get the underlying pure waveform (e.g. pulse), and the waveforms used in the sequence don't sound that way.